# php session.save_path not working

Tags: php, session

This code correctly sets a session as long as I don't try to set a session.save_path, if I do then the session never gets set.  I've tried various permutations but can't get one to work.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 90);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 90);
session_start();
$_SESSION['sid']=session_id();
header("location:profile.php");
```

These are the paths I have tried:-

```
ini_set('session.save_path', '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php2');
ini_set('session.save_path', '/Users/Alan/sessions');
ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/../sessions'));
```

Comment: have you look at your php conf if this is enabled¿'

Comment: `session.save_path` must be called before `session_start()` or it won't have any effect. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Make sure php/apache have the permission to write in the folder. It's not because you (as a user) can write in the folder that the user running your webserver (apache/php) can. Error log will warn you about this issue.